# How can roadside cafe quality be measured in Greece or Turkey?

Tags: food-and-drink, automobiles, road-trips, turkey, greece

When traveling by car it is always a big question how to determine the quality of roadside cafe in front of you.

In Russia I've noticed some dependency between quality of food and wares, although prices may be the same. Glass-ware cafe's usually have more quality food than plastic-ware cafe's. Also in Russia there is one good sign that there is good cafe in front of you - lots of lorries. Truckers usually eat at cafes with good food.

Is it generally true in Greece or Turkey?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "quality", there seems to be correlation with how elaborated the food is, but a simple grilled shashlik served with bread and cabbage salad might be better quality, than some more elaborated food.

Comment: Do you have locations in mind?

Comment: @Karlson As far as Russia is concerned - I know approximately how to find good cafe. Interested in Europe, but I don't know maybe there are no cafes in Europe that serve in plastic-ware ))

Comment: You should amend your question listing countries you would be interested in otherwise you the information will vary too much

Comment: @Karlson Fine added two European countries that I'm personally interested.

Comment: In Mexico, there's a pretty strong inverse correlation between the appearance of an eating establishment and the flavor of the food.

Answer (score 7):

Well for ***Turkey***, for road-side cafes and lorries, if there are many lorries, the that cafe is a cheap place where customers probably prefer *white beans and rice* (a popular duo for truckers). Below is a picture what I mean with *white beans and rice*

[image: white beans and rice]

I prefer you not to choose such places.

Beyond that, you probably will find have three type of restaurants:

- **Fast food restaurants**: You can find food like sandwiches and doner-kebab. Too cheap restaurants are not good, Since such thing are prepared in open kitchens, you can examine the meat and the other ingredients (salads etc...) before you can decide.

[image: Fast food restaurant]

- **Table d'hote Restaurants**: *Tabldot* in Turkish, these restaurants offers a few options for soups, main course and desert. They are a bit more expensive than fast food restaurants. Since all the food options are behind a glass covered desk, you can examine the food before you choose. You may even ask to taste it before you choose, since owner of the most such restaurants are polite people, that will not cause any problem. But after you taste something, it is not a good idea to change your mind on eating there, since that might be seem a bit unpolite.

[image: Table d'hote Restaurant]

- **Normal Restaurants**: These are normal restaurants you can find in every country, Have close kitchens and it is unlikely to get an idea about food quality and taste before you order something.

Answer (score 1):

99% sure that they are not good cafes. But where a lot of buses are stopped, they are really expensive. If it is only trucks, it is probably cheaper. But quality, I would say is hit or missed. I wouldn't judge something by the material their cutlery is made out of though.

But I would judge it by their restrooms.

Answer (score 0):

In Greece, you can find many coffee shops in every city. On the other hand, when you go on a road trip, this luxury is not easy... So, I suggest you get your take away coffee at the beginning of your trip or when you make your stop at the big resting places on the high way.

There are plenty of good quality Coffee Chains in Greece like: 
Coffee Island, Gregory's, Mikel, Coffee Lab, Everest, Starbucks and more...

Safe coffee choices when in Greece:
-Espresso (hot or cold)
-Cappuccino (hot or cold)
-Frappe (cold) or Nescafe (hot)
-Elleniko kafe (aka Greek coffee, hot)